# Earthquake clustering by pairs algorithm questions

Tags: oceanography, models, hydrogeology

A program I'm writing does the following:
(EQ=earthquake, EV=event, ML=machinelearning, etc)

- from a time series (in a selected station) it picks pairs of EQ' EVs with similar characteristics (magnitude/depth)
- from pairs, depth, magnitude it calculates individual force  for each of EV,
- for individual force, (with or without multiple stations added properties) it determines an approximate mass.


  We run this (simple and not too nested) pandas. Then how can we calculate the mechanical/kinetic entropy of EVs to add to pair properties for our algorithm evaluation?


  The model finally creates pairs clusters as single events (time independence) within the matching algorithm.

Are there any similar algorithms used for Earthquakes modelling?

Comment: Please spell out EQ, EV, ML for clarity